# OVS in English dialogue

Tags: syntax, english, grammar, verbs, word-order

English is an SVO language. When writing dialogue, especially in literature, writing a sentence with the speech first is considered grammatically correct. Take for example this extract from Ursula K Le Guin:

> "Enviable!" said the young Indweller.

Would the phrase "enviable" be the object of this sentence, as the patient of the transitive verb "to say"? A sentence like

> The young Indweller said "enviable!"

is far less literary, but fits with an SVO structure. Is this kind of literary way to display text an exception? Is speech not considered the object of a sentence?
"To say" isn't an intransitive verb, because you can't really say "he said" without specifying anything that was said.

Comment: I'd say that in both examples "enviable" is a verbless exclamative. In the first it's functioning as a main clause, and "said the young Indweller" is a parenthetical, a kind of supplement. In the second, "the young Indweller said" is superordinate to "enviable" which is complement (not object) to "said". Note, though, that "enviable!" is not a subordinate clause since it involves embedding of a **text**, not of a clause.

Comment: It is OVS and the object is indeed first. Why would you think it is not the object?

Comment: @siride Because objects are always noun phrases. There is no resemblance between "enviable" and a noun phrase object.

Comment: @BillJ it's quoted speech. The entire content within the quotes, whatever it may be, is a noun phrase from the perspective of the outer sentence. It doesn't matter what's inside, at all.

Comment: @siride I disagree. They don't have the form of NPs and hence aren't classified as NPs. As I've already explained, not every complement of a verb is an object.

Comment: In a typical example of direct reported speech such as _She replied, 'I live alone'_, the construction involves the embedding of a **text** as complement of "replied", so it's not a subordinate clause, and certainly not an NP!

Comment: @BillJ Then what is it? How do you think direct speech works? Why do you think the content of the direct speech has any bearing on the syntax of the main sentence? Nothing you've said makes any sense.

Comment: @BillJ Direct speech passes the constituency tests for noun phrases. You can replace the text with a pronoun ("she said it"). You can cleft it ("it was 'blah blah blah' that she said"). You can ask questions about it ("what did she say?" "she said 'blah blah blah'"). It fits inside the object position syntactically, just like a noun phrase. If you want to be pedantic, you could say it is a sibling to the concept of a noun phrase since it doesn't actually contain a noun. I would accept that. In any case, the important thing is that it is a single black box constituent, whatever you call it.

Comment: @siride Again, I disagree. I've repeatedly told you what it is: it's a text functioning as a complement of the reporting verb. The tests you mention prove nothing, otherwise every complement of a verb would be an NP! As I said, reported speech in an embedded construction is regarded as a text functioning as a complement. Even in, for example,  _She replied, 'I live alone'_, the reported element is not even a subordinate clause, let alone an NP.

Comment: @BillJ I don't think that's substantially different (and something can be both a complement and an object -- two different perspectives that, in this case, are the same). So given that, your very first comment makes no sense. "Enviable" is not a main clause in either version and there are no parentheticals either.

Comment: @siride An object is a sub-type of complement, but not all complements are objects, as is the case here. When we talk of complements that are objects, we do actually refer to them as objects, but elsewhere we simply use the term 'complement'. No one in my experience has ever had a problem with that terminology. In the non-embedded construction I call "Enviable" a verbless exclamative functioning as a main clause with the reporting frame having the status of a parethetical, a kind of supplement. In the embedded construction the reported speech is complement of the reporting verb "said".

Comment: Further, an exclamative clause often consists of just the exclamative phrase interpreted as a predicative complement, with be and the subject understood. Here, we understand something like "It's/that's enviable!"

Comment: To change the subject briefly, note that this is a matter of English **writing** practice, not the English language, or language in general. Spoken English does not use OVS structures like this, except for jokes or afterthoughts. Written narrative, on the other hand, uses them plenty.